# Using X509 Certificate without installing/saving it to store

Tags: asp.net, wcf, x509certificate2

Can we use X509certificate to send it with request to webservice without installing certificate on server or storing it in store .. ?I need to work o environment where i cant install certificate or can store it in store location.i can place this certificate in any directory then from that directory ,want to use that in request to web service.

Comment: Take a look at `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates`. It has the `X509Certificate2()` method with a lot of overloads. Including one where you can specify a local file.

Comment: yes..i know that but how to use that in calling web service.I am looking for that sample code.currently we are usnig web.config for that.

Comment: How do you want to use the certificate in code?